# preg_match bbcode

Tags: php, regex

I currently have bbcode like this

```
[caption=Some text goes here]image.jpg[/caption]
```

I'd like to use php's preg_match so I can get the value of the image.jpg, regardless of what's next to 'caption='. Can someone help me out?

Comment: For anyone reading this question, please don't reinvent the wheel, use an estabilished package. I authored one that I could recommend: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode , but take a look at others on Packagist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw regex:

```
]([^\]]+)[/caption]

preg_match("]([^\]]+)[/caption]", myString, $matches)
```

image.jpg would be in the first group.  `$matches[1]`
(I'm not certain I escaped it correctly in php).

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I was already pretty close, but couldnt' figure out how to "ignore" the text next to caption. Of course the obvious answer of just omitting that part of the code didn't cross my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
$str = '[caption=Some text goes here]image.jpg[/caption]';
if (preg_match('/^\[[^\]]+]([^[]+)/', $str, $arr))
   echo "image: $arr[1]\n";
```

#### OUTPUT

```
image: image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the complete bbcode tag, including the caption, use

`preg_match("/\[caption=(.+)\](.+)\[\/caption\]/", $myString, $matches);`

This will result in the following `$matches` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [caption=Some text goes here]image.jpg[/caption]
    [1] => Some text goes here
    [2] => image.jpg
)
```

Comment: The greedy dot matching will make this pattern prone to overmatching / inaccurate results.

Answer (score -1):

**[RegExp is not magic. PHP already has a pre-made extension library to handle BBCode.](http://web.archive.org/web/20180326101236/http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php)**

Don't reinvent the wheel, and don't make it hard on yourself.

Comment: this link is dead